# JSP Page display date from collection

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am new to JSP and servlet.

I am trying to have list from servlet and wants to display those data into JSP page.

Here is what I did

My Servlet class

```
List<User> list = friendsDao.getFirendsList(user.getEmail());
System.out.println("List Size:"+list.size());
req.setAttribute("list", list);
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

My JSP Page

I have added this tag library

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

and here is what I am doing to iterate the data

```
<table>
    <c:forEach var="friend" items="${list}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${friend}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${friend.email}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

but this is not working

but when I am trying to have something like this

```
<%
    }
    List<User> list = (List<User>) request.getAttribute("list");
%>


    <table>
        <c:forEach var="friend" items="<%=list%>">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${friend.name}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${friend.email}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

This is also not working but, it at list iterate the loop to the size of data. **but in browser it prints**

**${friend.name} ${friend.eamil}**

How can I have actual values in there.
Please help me with this.

Thanks,
Nixit

Comment: Can you check the typo in user bean  getter and setter ?

Comment: do i need to use gettter setter or just the field name

Comment: tried that as well but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohk I got the solution,

I don't know the reason, but jsp file requires me to put this one line of code. in order to tag library to work

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
    <c:forEach var="friend" items="<%=list%>">
```

to

```
    <c:forEach var="friend" items="${list}">
```

because by `<%=list%>` it is outputting the value right there, and you don't need reference to `List<User>` in `jsp`

Comment: it doesn't iterate the loop and also not showing the data, it just print whatever is inside c tag one time

Comment: are you sure `list` is available not null iterable ?

Comment: I am getting value by this:     List<User> list = (List<User>) request.getAttribute("list");